# Can a creature hide from a foe affected by the feat Gloom Strike?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sneak-attack, concealment

The ambush feat Gloom Strike (*Drow of the Underdark* 54) has as its benefit

> Your sneak attack creates an aura of magical darkness that impedes your target’s vision for 3 rounds. The target takes a −4 penalty on Spot checks and treats all other creatures as having concealment. Neither darkvision nor low-light vision pierces this effect, though the ability to see through magical darkness does. Any spell with the light descriptor suppresses the effect.

Is the concealment generated by the feat Gloom Strike sufficient for a creature to use the Hide skill to hide from that affected foe? If so, after hiding can the hidden creature deal sneak attack damage to the affected foe?

Comment: Does the campaign use the [*Rules Compendium*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/8610)?

Comment: Idk, the gm wants to know why we should use it. would that help in any case?

Comment: The *PH* rules for hiding are frustrating and vague but functional while the *Rules Compendium* rules for hiding are precise, powerful, and legally suspect. The DM should decide at the campaign's outset whether to include the *Rules Compendium* — whether in sections or in its entirety — because if introduced *after* the campaign's begun, its rules changes are substantial enough that it may sow confusion, dissent, and hurt feelings.

Comment: We are level 3 atm so we have time to change and i am the only one in the party that uses hide. Also we have never face a creature that hid from us so far. I think that it might be able to be changed in that one aspect

Comment: It's a *really* good idea to read [this question and its answers](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28378/8610) before making a decision to see which way the group prefers.

Answer (score 2):

## Not really

Gloom Strike covers the “cover-or-concealment” requirement of the Hide skill, but not the “cannot-be-directly-observed” requirement. The target is partially blinded, hence the concealment, but not fully blind: he can still observe you (and presumably would).

If you had a version of Hide in Plain Sight that still required cover-or-concealment (e.g. the Dark template from *Tome of Magic*), however, you could hide. Having hidden, [your attacks would then qualify for Sneak Attack bonus damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28378/4563).

Comment: Note: the Dark template can be obtained via the *Collar of Umbral Metamorphosis*.